# Delete Custom Fields in TFS 2010

Tags: templates, field

I'm using TFS2010 with TFS Productivity Tools installed.

If you delete a Custom field via Template Editor, the field still shows up in Global Field Explorer.

How to actually 'hard delete' a custom field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have removed the field from all the Work Item Type Definitions, you need to use the [`witadmin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd236914%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tool with the  [`deletefield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd236909%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command from the Developer Command Prompt.

The command line syntax is:

```
witadmin deletefield /collection:CollectionURL /n:RefName [/noprompt]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a custom field using Azure DevOps portal:

1. Navigate to Organization settings
2. Select the Boards ==> processes page
3. Choose the Fields tab
4. In Filter by field name box (upper right) begin typing field name
5. Click the elipse (...) next to the field name and choose 'X delete'